# Magento 2 : get Mysql Query of products

Tags: product, database, magento2.3.4, query

I wanna show in my mysql query of all attributes name,product name, product status is 1 and sku but in my query its not showing product name and status so could you help me in my this query ?

```
 SELECT  ce.entity_id ,s.attribute_set_name,sk.sku,a.attribute_id FROM catalog_product_entity_int ce
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity sk ON sk.entity_id = ce.entity_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_set s ON sK.attribute_set_id = s.attribute_set_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute a ON a.attribute_id = ce.attribute_id WHERE a.attribute_code LIKE 'status' AND ce.value = 1
```

it showing below result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change you SQL query as below

```
SELECT  ce.entity_id , s.attribute_set_name, sk.sku, skv.value as 
product_name, a.attribute_id FROM catalog_product_entity_int ce
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity sk ON sk.entity_id = ce.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar skv ON sk.entity_id = skv.entity_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_set s ON sk.attribute_set_id = s.attribute_set_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute a ON a.attribute_id = ce.attribute_id WHERE a.attribute_code LIKE 'status' AND ce.value = 1
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but in product_name column its showing product name and as well as its other attribute value like option value , product url key.. in product_name column it should be only product name only

Comment: in the first line "SELECT  ce.entity_id , s.attribute_set_name, sk.sku, skv.value as 
product_name" here you can change 'product_name' to whatever you want.

Comment: I am not talking about product_name column text sir I am getting the other attribute value in product name column so I want only product name attribute value in product name textbox